# MongoDB. Query for array in Subdocument

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

i am new to mongodb so please correct me if i am using the wrong terms:

I have the following document(excerpt)

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("524b0a1a7294ec8a39d4230f"),
    "name" : "Irbesartan",
    "decompositions" : [
            "IRB_444",
            "IRB_442",
            "IRB_446",
            "Valsartan acid"
    ],
    "precursor" : [
            {
                    "mass" : 429,
                    "ion" : "+H",
                    "charge" : "+",
                    "fragments" : [
                            207,
                            195,
                            180
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "mass" : 427.2252,
                    "ion" : "-H",
                    "charge" : "-",
                    "fragments" : [
                            193,
                            399
                    ]
            }
    ]
}
```

With

```
db.substances.findOne({name: "Irbesartan"}).precursor
```

i get the following

```
[
    {
            "mass" : 429,
            "ion" : "+H",
            "charge" : "+",
            "fragments" : [
                    207,
                    195,
                    180
            ]
    },
    {
            "mass" : 427.2252,
            "ion" : "-H",
            "charge" : "-",
            "fragments" : [
                    193,
                    399
            ]
    }
]
```

But i want to acces the fields inside, espacially the fragment array (using Mongo Shell)

Is this possible in one query?

Or is it better to store the precursor as an array instead of a subdocument?

Answer (score 1):

For example query

```
db.substances.distinct("precursor.fragments", {name: "Irbesartan"})
```

gives:

```
[ 180, 193, 195, 207, 399 ]
```

or

```
db.substances.findOne({name: "Irbesartan"}).precursor.map(function(r) {
  return r.fragments;
})
```

gives

```
[ [ 207, 195, 180 ], [ 193, 399 ] ]
```

Comment: Thank you, i will give it a try tomorrow. Is this possible db.substances.distinct("precursor.mass", {name: "Irbesartan"})?